# most pythonic way to create list of dictionaries based on bool of another dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Here's my situation - I have a dictionary:

```
dic = {"al" : False,
       "ol" : True,
       "psc": True,
       "cp" : False}
```

Then I have three other `dict`s defined somewhere else which we'll just imagine we imported, so they exist as variables in the namespace of the module.

```
 appointmentslist_params  # al 
 officerlist_params       # ol
 psc_params               # psc
 companyprofile_params    # cp
```

Now, I want to create a list containing those `dict`s based on the bool of the dict above.

My current solution is:

```
params_ls = []
if dic["ol"]:
    params_ls.append(officerlist_params)
if dic["psc"]:
    params_ls.append(psc_params)
if dic["al"]:
    params_ls.append(appointmentslist_params)
if dic["cp"]:
    params_ls.append(companyprofile_params)
```

I was simply wondering if there was a more pythonic way - this is very readable but not very DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another dictionary to associate the imported dictionaries with the corresponding key:

```
d1 = {'al':appointmentslist_params, 'ol':officerlist_params, 'psc':psc_params, 'cp':companyprofile_params}
dic = {"al" : False,
   "ol" : True,
   "psc": True,
   "cp" : False}

params_ls = [b for a, b in d1.items() if dic[a]]
```

Comment: Might be worth to point out that in Python < 3.7 the order of `params_ls` is not guaranteed, if it matters.